# why do flex items wrap when we set margin or gaps to the items?

Tags: css

when we add gap to flex container or add margin to items of a normal container, it automatically wraps one item to the down if we set the width as 1/3. as we know margin is not included to the width (box-content). also same result if we add margin to the items. why does this happen ?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Flex Examples</title>
    <script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
  </head>
  <body>  
    <div id="flex-container"
      class="flex flex-wrap justify-between gap-2 m-2 bg-yellow-100 border-4 border-green-900 border-solid"
    >
      <div class="w-1/3 text-xl text-center bg-red-100">item-1</div>
      <div class="w-1/3 text-xl text-center bg-green-100">item 2</div>
      <div class="w-1/3 text-xl text-center bg-blue-100">item 3</div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

same affect when we apply for normal container. item3 wraps.

```html
    <div id="normal-container" class="">
      <div class="inline-block w-1/3 mr-2 text-xl text-center bg-red-100">item-1</div>
      <div class="inline-block w-1/3 mr-2 text-xl text-center bg-green-100">item 2</div>
      <div class="inline-block w-1/3 mr-2 text-xl text-center bg-blue-100">item 3</div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

"Thank you for the provided HTML example. I noticed that when using the w-1/3 (width: 33.3333%) classes along with the gap-2 class, it results in one of the items wrapping to the next line. This behavior is due to the combination of the specified width and the gap. The gap property introduces additional space between the items, and this space is added to the total width of each item.

To address this, you can either consider reducing the gap size or adjusting the width value to ensure that the items, when combined with the gap, fit within the container width. This will prevent the wrapping behavior and maintain the desired layout.

Here's an example with a reduced gap size:

```
 <div id="flex-container"
  class="flex flex-wrap justify-between gap-1 m-2 bg-yellow-100 border-4 border-green-900 border-solid"
>
  <div class="w-1/3 text-xl text-center bg-red-100">item-1</div>
  <div class="w-1/3 text-xl text-center bg-green-100">item 2</div>
  <div class="w-1/3 text-xl text-center bg-blue-100">item 3</div>
</div>
```

Or, adjust the width value to accommodate the gap:

```
<div id="flex-container"
  class="flex flex-wrap justify-between gap-2 m-2 bg-yellow-100 border-4 border-green-900 border-solid"
>
  <div class="w-1/4 text-xl text-center bg-red-100">item-1</div>
  <div class="w-1/4 text-xl text-center bg-green-100">item 2</div>
  <div class="w-1/4 text-xl text-center bg-blue-100">item 3</div>
</div>
```

Choose the approach that best fits your design requirements.

Comment: thanks, when we specify width:%33 , it is %33 of the parent width , but when we set an absolute widht like px , it excludes margin, but for the percentage unit, it doesnt exclude margin.